# how to disable href tag if file is already uploaded using thymleaf

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using th:disabled and it is disabling button but still clickable, this is the thymeleaf code I have done so far.
I want to disable file upload button when user has done final submit of application. and for that I am checking this condition:
th:disabled="${lst.finalSubmit !=null}"

this is the screenshot: (https://prnt.sc/10cny2t)

```
<div class="card-body" id="myDIV" onblur="chekforblank()">
    <table id="TblGrievance" class="table table-striped table-bordered"
        style="width: 100%">
        <thead>
            <tr class="bg-secondary">
                <!-- <th>Sn.</th> -->
                <th>Reference Number</th>
                <th>Grievance Date</th>
                <th>Phone NO</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <!-- <th>&nbsp;</th> -->
            </tr>

            <tr th:each="lst : ${dto}" id="ll">
                <th th:text="${lst.refno}"></th>
                <th th:text="${lst.finalSubmit}"></th>
                <th th:text="${lst.phoneOfOrg}"></th>
                <th th:text="${lst.complaintStatus}"></th>
                
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        
                        <a th:href="@{/uploadDraft/{id}(id=${lst.refno})}" title="You have already Uplaoded your docmuents"><button
                class="btn btn-primary" th:disabled="${lst.finalSubmit !=null}">File Upload</button></a>
                        
                    <a th:href="@{/viewComplaint/{refno}(refno=${lst.refno})}"><i
                        class="fa fa-list-alt fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>


        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "_it is disabling button but still clickable_". If you mean the cursor changes shape when you hover over the button, then you can control that with a suitable style - for example:  `<button class="btn btn-primary" disabled="true" style="cursor: auto;">File Upload</button>`. That would be better as a CSS class, not as an embedded style - but this is a quick demo. If that is not what you mean, then can you [edit] your question and clarify the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue with this line of the code ...

```
<a th:href="@{/uploadDraft/{id}(id=${lst.refno})}" title="You have already Uplaoded your docmuents">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" th:disabled="${lst.finalSubmit !=null}">File Upload
    </button>
</a>
```

The button which you are trying to disable wrapped into the anchor tag. When your button disabled by Thymeleaf condition the link around still work and the button is clickable, even though it looks disabled.
To fix it, you should, first of all, read Bootstrap documentation on [Disabled state](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/buttons/#disabled-state) of the buttons. Bootstrap allows to present buttons as `<button>` or `<a>` tags. Please, pay attention to the important notes regarding disabling `<a>` tag, where the main one is ...

> `<a>`s don’t support the disabled attribute, so you must add the `.disabled` class to make it visually appear disabled.

After reading choose what tag would you like to use for your upload button, for example, if you would like to use `<a>` tag your code may look like ...

```
<a th:href="@{/uploadDraft/{id}(id=${lst.refno})}" title="You have already Uplaoded your docmuents" 
class="btn btn-primary" th:classappend="${lst.finalSubmit !=null}? 'disabled'">File Upload</a>
```